# Mount UFS partition on CentOS 7

Tags: kernel-module, centos-7, ufs

There is instructions to mount UFS partitions on CentOS ([like this](http://linux-bsd-sharing.blogspot.de/2012/05/howto-mount-ufs-partition-on-centos-sl.html)), but they use `kmod-ufs` package from ELRepo, and there isn't such package in ELRepo for CentOS 7.

How to install UFS kernel module for CentOS 7? Alternatively, How I can compile this module from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the instructions in http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules to build the UFS kernel module (ufs.ko).

Note that (in step 3) it's necessary to compile the whole kernel (takes about 1 hour)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code in my case

```
rpm -ivh http://rpm.repo.onapp.com/repo/rhel/7/x86_64/RPMS-5.2/kmod-ufs-3.10.0-9.onapp.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).